# How to filter Packets in RAW socket in LINUX

Tags: c, linux, raw-sockets

RAW Socket: How to filter packets in `RAW Socket` ? I was trying to capture `UDP packets` in a server Program but its receiving all the packets. Is there any function or command to filter the packets in linux.

Comment: Check the protocol field of the IP header and ignore everything that is not UDP.

Comment: A simple solution would be to just use UDP sockets. If that's not an option for whatever reason, you're going to have to do the work manually -- what the previous commenter suggested would work.

Comment: @scai now i am able to receive packets, i have written some cases while receiving the packets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use LSF/BPF (see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/filter.txt an http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bpf&sektion=4) or for a higher-level interface, [pcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html)

Comment: while receiving we can put some cases to control the packets.

Answer (score 1):

```
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>

 raw_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, int protocol);
```

Using this protocol Field we can capture particular packet.

```
int fd = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
char buffer[8192]; /* single packets are usually not bigger than 8192 bytes */
while (read (fd, buffer, 8192) > 0)
{
     printf ("Caught tcp packet: %s\n", 
     buffer+sizeof(struct iphdr)+sizeof(struct tcphdr));
}
```

above code will capture all TCP packets. Similarly for UDP we can use

`socket (PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);`