# Raw socket: filter only packets coming from a certain IP address? (Linux C)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ip-address

I have a C Linux program that uses raw sockets to read incoming tcp/udp packets.

I would like to apply a filter so that only packets sent from a certain IP address reach my socket.

Is it possibile or am I supposed to receive necessarily every packets and then check source address field? I'm a bit concerned about cpu usage in the latter case.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter Packets in RAW socket in LINUX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852486/how-to-filter-packets-in-raw-socket-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on the processor that is being used by you. Some processor have features such as built-in hardware to filter packets based on rules involving input port, source ip address and type of protocol(TCP / UDP / etc..). This in-turn can reduce the load as hardware filtering has better performance than software filtering.